# Not able to call microservice using express-http-proxy in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

This code is of gateway service which is running on 8000 port from which I am calling the other 3 services, The issue is, I am  able to call '/customer' and '/' service from gateway as follows http://localhost:8000/customer and http://localhost:8000 but http://localhost:8000/shopping service is not getting called and it shows error Cannot GET /shopping/checking from Postman.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const proxy = require("express-http-proxy");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use("/customer", proxy("http://localhost:8001"));
app.use("/", proxy("http://localhost:8002")); // Product service
app.use("/shopping", proxy("http://localhost:8003"));

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("Gateway Listening on 8000 port");
});
```

Can you please help me with this issue.

Comment: There is no `/shopping/checking` path in your code

Comment: I have defined '/shopping/checking' path in another service and this call is made from Gateway service